# Parse ajax query with play querystringbind

Tags: jquery, ajax, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

By default, when one has a route to an action that takes a list parameter

```
GET /list controllers.Application.index(ids: List[Long])
```

Play expects that the request uri looks like

```
/list?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3
```

But Jquery.ajax by default sends request as

```
/list?ids%5B%5D=1&ids%5B5D=2&ids%5B%5D=3
```

Play has something called [QueryStringBindable](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0-M1/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.QueryStringBindable) that may be used to change this behavior. Isn't it ? If it can be used to solve this issue, how to implements may custom querybinders ?
Or is there another solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better using the JavaScript routing support in Play.

In your controller, add the following method

```
def jsRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
    controllers.routes.javascript.Application.index))
  .as("text/javascript")
}
```

Expose it in your routes file, above the /assets/*file entry

```
GET    /assets/js/routes     controllers.Application.jsRoutes()
GET    /assets/*file         controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Add a  tag to your view to get the JavaScript it generates

```
<script src="@controllers.routes.Application.jsRoutes()" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Finally, instead of using jQuery to make the AJAX call, you can use an object that is aware of the routing requirements:

```
jsRoutes.controllers.Application.index(id1, id2, etc).ajax( {
      success : function (data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        // do something on success 
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // do something on error
      },
      complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        // do something on complete
      }
    });
```

There's an additional benefit here in that if you change your index() route to use path parameters instead of query parameters, no change is required in the JavaScript - the routing object will handle this for you.

**References**

Scala: http://www.objectify.be/wordpress/?p=746

Java: http://www.objectify.be/wordpress/?p=734

**Edit:** For single-page apps

There are two approaches you can use for single-page applications.

**1.** Create a controller that exposes every route you want to access for AJAX.  For example, for the routes file

```
GET   /foo     controllers.FooController.foo()
GET   /bar     controllers.BarController.bar()
```

you can have a (e.g.) JsRoutesController controller that has a function

```
def jsRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
    controllers.routes.javascript.FooController.foo)),
    controllers.routes.javascript.BarController.bar))
 .as("text/javascript")
}
```

Update your routes

```
GET    /assets/js/routes     controllers.JsRoutesController.jsRoutes()
```

and then access it using

```
<script src="/js/routes" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or **2.** The JS object name is specified in the jsRoutes function (Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes") in the above example).  You can have a jsRoutes function per controller which exposes a controller-specific JS routing object.

In FooController:

```
def jsRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(Routes.javascriptRouter("fooRoutes")(
    controllers.routes.javascript.FooController.foo))
 .as("text/javascript")
}
```

In BarController:

```
def jsRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(Routes.javascriptRouter("barRoutes")(
    controllers.routes.javascript.BarController.bar))
 .as("text/javascript")
}
```

Update your routes file

```
GET    /assets/js/foo/routes     controllers.FooController.jsRoutes()
GET    /assets/js/bar/routes     controllers.BarController.jsRoutes()
```

And in your page

```
<script src="/js/foo/routes" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/bar/routes" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Nothing in either approach requires Play 2's view layer.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. This solution is interesting but we develop our client code as single page javascript application based on emberjs and we don't use the view element of play. So we need to mock this jsRoutes during the client development. How to achieve this easily ?

Comment: 2 ways, but details are required; see updated answer.